# Elasticsearch match and not match

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to do a search in Elasticsearch to find the results with some criterias including:

1. find the phrase "MICE DROPPINGS were OBSERVED" in the violations field,
2. exclude the phrase "NO MICE DROPPINGS were OBSERVED" in the violations field.

Here is part of my code:

```
query ={
      'size' : 10000,
      'query': {
          "bool" : {
              "should":[    {'match' : {'Facility Type': {"query" : 'Daycare (2 - 6 Years)',"operator":"and"}}},
                            {'match' : {'Facility Type':{"query" : 'Daycare Above and Under 2 Years',"operator": "and"}}},
                            {'match' : {'Facility Type':{"query" : 'CHILDRENS SERVICES FACILITY',"operator" : "and"}}},
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match" : 1,
                        "filter" : [{"match" : {'Results': {"query": 'Fail', "operator": "and"}}},
                                    {"match" : {'Risk': {"query": 'Risk 1 (High)', "operator": "and"}}},
                                    {"match" : {'Violations': {"query": '%MICE DROPPINGS were OBSERVED%', "operator": "and"}}},
                                    ],             
            "must_not" : {"match" : {'Violations': {"query": '%NO MICE DROPPINGS were OBSERVED%', "operator": "and"}}},
              },
                                  
      }
```

What I got is just one record, and I am expecting more than that.

What did I do wrong? This is my first time to use Elasticsearch and no idea how it works exactly.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [match phrase query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html). Adding a working example

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "violations": "MICE DROPPINGS were OBSERVED"
}
{
  "violations": "MICE were OBSERVED"
}
{
  "violations": "MICE DROPPINGS were OBSERVED today"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_phrase": {
          "violations": "MICE DROPPINGS were OBSERVED"
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
         "match_phrase": {
          "violations": "No MICE DROPPINGS were OBSERVED"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also achieve your result using match query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "violations": {
            "query": "MICE DROPPINGS were OBSERVED",
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
        "match": {
          "violations": {
            "query": "No MICE DROPPINGS were OBSERVED",
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66575233",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.87059784,
        "_source": {
          "violations": "MICE DROPPINGS were OBSERVED"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @PhilipShangguan Sure, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: I just tested it and the first search worked, but it only came out 3 records which still not right, but I will check the DB. The second search got the following error: RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', '[match_phrase] query does not support [operator]')

Comment: @PhilipShangguan can you please run the second search query again ?

Comment: I will try it today and let you know. Thx!

Comment: i tested the search query again last night and it worked. Thanks. Now I have a aggregation question that I need help with. I will post in a separate note. Thanks again!